# Frequent Error when deploying Helm to GKE with Terraform

Tags: terraform, kubernetes-helm

Components

1. GKE
2. Helm v3
3. Terraform

---

> **Note**: The below error is raised, BUT IF i keep doing `terraform apply/delete` multiple times, it would somehow auto-resolve. I am making use of Google Cloud Console so there is no chacne of my Internet messing things up.

**Error Type 1**:

```
Error: Error reading ComputeNetwork "projects/foo/global/networks/bar-network": Get https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/foo/global/networks/bar-network-e4l6-network?alt=json: dial tcp [1111:2222:4003:c03::5f]:443: connect: cannot assign requested address
```

**Error Type 2**:

```
Error reading Service Account "projects/foo/serviceAccounts/bar-sa@foo.iam.gserviceaccount.com": Get https://iam.googleapis.com/v1/projects/foo/serviceAccounts/example-cluster-sa@dravoka2.iam.gserviceaccount.com?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: dial tcp [1111:2222:4003:c04::5f]:443: connect: cannot assign requested address
```

**Error Type 3**:

```
Error: Error retrieving available container cluster versions: Get https://container.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/foo/locations/us-central1-c/serverConfig?alt=json&prettyPrint=false: dial tcp [1111:2222:4003:c03::5f]:443: connect: cannot assign requested address
```

**Error Type 4**:

```
Error reading instance group manager returned as an instance group URL: "googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/foo/zones/us-central1-c/instanceGroupManagers/gke-bar-main-pool-8c2b8edd-grp' was not found, notFound"
```

I don't understand why it popsup randomly, and when I re-run the same terraform apply/delete it magically works fine!

Any guidance would help.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem, and after several hours of looking at it in more detail - i think I know what is happening and how to work around it. Since implementing the following workaround, I've had 100% success rate in apply/destroy operations.

Problem:

For some reason, Terraform is accepting the AAAA (IPv6) record over the A record. You can see this in the error response as the record for the *.googleapis.com is an IPv6 address. As Google Cloud Console doesn't have IPv6 enabled, this is why you're getting this error. It seems this is a problem with Go, rather than Terraform itself based on the searches I did for similar errors.

Solution:

Short of changing the source code in Terraform, you can instead modify your /etc/hosts file to respond with an IPv4 address for each of the APIs Terraform calls. As the Cloud Shell is hosted on Google Cloud, you can use the Private Google Access IPs (199.36.153.8/30). To automate this, just put the following in your .customize_environment file in your home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
export APIS="googleapis.com www.googleapis.com storage.googleapis.com iam.googleapis.com container.googleapis.com cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com"
for i in $APIS
do
  echo "199.36.153.10 $i" >> /etc/hosts
done
chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

For reference, I created an [issue in the Google provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-google/issues/6782) to track it.

Update 2023: You need to make /etc/hosts immutable as it now gets periodically overwritten. Add `chattr +i`

Comment: Did you mean? ```export APIS=("googleapis.com" "www.googleapis.com" "storage.googleapis.com" "iam.googleapis.com" "container.googleapis.com" "cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com")
for i in $APIS
do
  echo "199.36.153.10 $i" >> /etc/hosts
done``` and for me 216.58.212.164 worked

Comment: @IddanAaronsohn Are you using Google Cloud Shell in your example? Because it works if you use Cloud Shell and place it in your .customize_environment file. 216.58.212.164 is an ephemeral IP and may change, so I wouldn't rely on this. If you are indeed on a non-cloud shell, a better approach would be to configure DNS not to return AAAA records at all.

Comment: At the worst times, it was a little better than local. How can I configure DNS not to return AAAA record at all?